# Custom Authorization attribute asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to create custom authorization attribute for my asp.net core application. I have seen this post and I am aware of the 2 approaches discussed here.
[How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)

1) Using IAuthorizationFilter

2) Using Policies

I saw that the official document suggests that we should be using policies and not  IAuthorizationFilter but I felt that using policies for my scenario is an overkill. I personally liked IAuthorizationFilter approach more.

I have a very basic requirement. I want to create an authorize attribute for my web api and need to throw 403 if the current user is not whitelisted to use this API. I really don't care about the scopes(canRead, canWrite, can readWrite etc). If I go ahead with policy approach, I may be using the same policy for all my APIs. 
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using policies for something like this isn't overkill. You need a requirement:

```
public class WhitelistRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

A handler:

```
public class WhitelistHandler : AuthorizationHandler<WhitelistRequirement>
{

    // Implement a constructor to inject dependencies, such as your whitelist

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   WhitelistRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (isInWhitelist) // Your implementation here
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register both in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("WhitelistPolicy",
            b => b.AddRequirements(new WhitelistRequirement())));

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, WhitelistHandler>();
```

Then use your policy:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "WhitelistPolicy")]
```

You can apply the policy globally with a global filter:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .AddRequirements(new WhitelistRequirement())
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

The resulting behavior for unauthenticated or forbidden users depends on the implementation of the "challenge" and "forbid" behaviors in your app's authentication handler.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#applying-policies-to-razor-pages).

Comment: Same as with a controller or anything else - create a constructor that receives any needed dependencies, then make sure those dependencies are registered. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: still isn't this too much work when compared to custom Authorization attribute? (eg. with custom Authorization attribute there is no bootstrapping in `Startup.cs`) Is there a specific downside of using custom Authorization attribute when compared over Authorization Policy + Requirement + Handler implementation? Sure, policy based authorization provides great extendability in terns of being able to have multiple Handlers for one Requirement etc. but.. is there a drawback in using custom Authorization attribute when a given authorization need is quite rudimentary?